# Unique Values in a Combo Box in Access

Tags: sql, combobox

Ok, here is my dilemma. (Using Access 2010)

I have created a access db, to manage the computer hardware inventory at my job.
I created a Form with a unbound combo box allowing only unique values. Also on the form I added a report, that will match all applicable equipment to a username. The goal is when I click "John Smith" it will show all the items "John Smith" has (I have gotten this to work).

This Combo Box does pull its data from a Table, where there are multiples of the same name in different rows.

Here is the SQL Code for the Combo Box

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Master Inventory].ID, [Master Inventory].User
FROM [Master Inventory]
ORDER BY [Master Inventory].User;
```

The issue is that my Combo Box Still shows multiples of same names even though I have told to use Unique Values. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try removing the [Master Inventory].id column, it appears that since the combo box shows one field, but you query returns distinct list of two fields.   Not sure which field you are trying to load into the combo box though, whichever one, remove the other column and try it.

Answer (score 0):

The Id field will make each row distinct. if you remove that column it should give you the names only once.

Comment: When I remove the ID field,

 
    SELECT DISTINCT [Master Inventory].User
    FROM [Master Inventory]
    ORDER BY [Master Inventory].User;

and my SQL looks like this, the combobox is blank. the ID field is also my Primary key. The .User column on my table is the values I want to fill my Combobox with.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else wondering the answer for this question. This is something that worked in my case (ACCESS 2016) and it's pretty straight forward:

```
SELECT DISTINCT User
FROM [Master Inventory];
```

The order display is up to you based on your preference (you add ORDER BY based on the criteria).

One thing to be carefull. The brackets in the table name are added only if the table name has space inside.

Answer (score 0):

Make the below query manually (don't use wizard)

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT User
FROM [Master Inventory];
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35821249)